# Compare and validate two seperate inputs with a PHP form

Tags: php, sql, forms, compare, validation

Scenario:

A PHP form with two inputs, namely:

Character Name:

Character URL:

The character name is within the "<*title><*/title>" of a webpage. I'd  like the form to compare the input of the character name with the name within the "<*title><*/title>" of the submitted character URL, and if it's valid, post the data to a SQL db. That's it.

e.g

Character Name: GreatOne

Character URL: http://somewebsite.com/char/828282/

Within the page source is "<*title>GreatOne - SomeWebsite<*/title>"

It needs to compare the two names and execute what I said above before posting the data to the SQL db. I'm not a programmer, and I can't go and learn a language just for this script, but I need it urgently to test something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so you want us to do your work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename = $CharacterUrl;
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

if (strstr($contents, $CharacterName)) { 
    // do something because whatever their name is appears in the contents of the url
} else {
   // they don't exist
}
```

Almost 1:1 from the http://www.php.net/ site

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

$url = $_post['characterurl'];
$url = file_get_contents[$url];
preg_match('/title>(.*?)</title>/', $url, $url);
$title = $url[1];
if($title==$_post['charactername']){
// post to db
}else{
// do something other than post to db
}

I would also put both title variables to lowercase and do the htmlspecialchars function too.